# get init issue after extending couchdb with geocouch on ubuntu

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchdb-futon

The env is ubuntu 12.10. the src version are **apache-couchdb-1.2.1** and
**geocouch-couchdb1.2.x**, 
first try i just put both to the Download folder, but when i execute make in
geocouch folder then got below issue :

```
ryu@ryu-Asp:~/Downloads/geocouch-couchdb1.2.x$ make
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I dont found the resolution on google so just ignore this issue, continue the
configure base on https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/tree/couchdb1.2.x. :

```
sudo cp etc/couchdb/default.d/geocouch.ini /usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.d/
export ERL_FLAGS="-pa /usr/local/src/geocouch/ebin"
ryu@ryu-Asp:/usr/local/bin$ sudo ./couchdb
```

then got below error message :

```
Apache CouchDB 1.2.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting. 
[error] [<0.93.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                {<0.93.0>,supervisor_report,
                 [{supervisor,{local,couch_secondary_services}},
                  {errorContext,start_error},
                  {reason,
                   {'EXIT',
                    {undef,
                     [{couch_spatial,start_link,[],[]},
                      {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,303}]},
                      {supervisor,start_children,3,
                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,287}]},
                      {supervisor,init_children,2,
                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,253}]},
                      {gen_server,init_it,6,
                       [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                       [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}}},
                  {offender,
                   [{pid,undefined},
                    {name,spatial_manager},
                    {mfargs,{couch_spatial,start_link,[]}},
                    {restart_type,permanent},
                    {shutdown,brutal_kill},
                    {child_type,worker}]}]}}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal, ["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',   {{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 23-Feb-2013::16:24:04 ===
 Supervisor: {local,couch_secondary_services}
 Context:    start_error
 Reason:     {'EXIT',
                 {undef,
                     [{couch_spatial,start_link,[],[]},
                      {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                          [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,303}]},
                      {supervisor,start_children,3,
                          [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,287}]},
                      {supervisor,init_children,2,
                          [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,253}]},
                      {gen_server,init_it,6,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}}
 Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
              {name,spatial_manager},
              {mfargs,{couch_spatial,start_link,[]}},
              {restart_type,permanent},
              {shutdown,brutal_kill},
              {child_type,worker}]

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Btw , i have tried the method of putting the src to /usr/local/src on http://euroside.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/installing-geocouch/. but it still not work.

Comment: finally I found it all my fault, i add the export statement in ~/.bashrc instead of /etc/environment